# Let the user choose which function to run

Tags: python

```py
x = input("Enter your First No. :")
y = input("Enter your Second No. :")
z = input("Choose your Function:")
print(z)

a = int(x) + int(y)
m = int(x) * int(y)
s = int(x) - int(y)
d = int(x) / int(y)

if z == a:
      print("Here's your solution:" + a)
elif z == m:
    print("Here's your solution:" + m)
elif z == s:
    print("Here's your solution:" + s)
elif z == d:
    print("Here's your solution:" + d)
```

Now, I would like it to work like a calculator but on running it keeps showing this in the terminal

```
Enter your First No. :3
Enter your Second No. :6
Choose your Function: a


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: You need to compare z to the strings, not the results i.e `z == "a"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Ashish* is of course right.

Just for completeness this is how I would write it.

```
# transform into integers here already
x = int(input("Enter your First No. :"))
y = int(input("Enter your Second No. :"))

# give this a reasonable name
operator = input("Choose you Function:\n i.e. multiply/divide/plus/minus:")
print(operator)

# only calculate the values when needed.

if operator == 'plus':
      print("Here's your solution:", x + y)

elif operator == 'multiply':
    print("Here's your solution:", x * y)

elif operator == 'minus':
    print("Here's your solution:", x - y)

elif operator == 'divide':
    print("Here's your solution:", x / y)

elif operator == 'to the power of':
    print("Here's your solution:", x ** y)

else:
    print("Sorry, I'm afraid I can't do this!")
```

Answer (score 2):

Compare z with function name not with the result of function. This works fine.
I think Is much better to add to lower function in order to catch user input and to convert it to lowercase letters.

```
x = input("Enter your First No. :")
y = input("Enter your Second No. :")

z = input("Choose you Function:\n i.e. multiply/divide/plus/minus:").lower()
print(z)

a = int(x) + int(y)

m = int(x) * int(y)

s = int(x) - int(y)

d = int(x) / int(y)

if z == 'plus':
      print("Here's your solution:" + a)

elif z == 'multiply':
    print("Here's your solution:" + m)

elif z == 'minus':
    print("Here's your solution:" + s)

elif z == 'divide':
    print("Here's your solution:" + d)
```

Comment: BTW, it would be easier if you did the conversion to integer only once.